# Swap Contents of WebViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have 2 WebViews, which load 2 webpages.

How do I swap their contents? So I would get the content of one WebView, and set the content of the other WebView to this, and visa versa?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I think it would be something like

```
[_mainWebView setContent:_subWebView];
```

But I can't find anything for it.

EDIT: I think I'd have to use WebView's WebFrame, but how do I set it?

Comment: What about swapping the position of the two views instead of their underlying contents?

Comment: @fbrereto i would do that but the webviews are of different sizes and in very specific positions, is it not possible to swap the content only?

Comment: You can swap the sizes and positions of the two webviews more easily.

Comment: @hotpaw2 please post an answer on how I would do this, including swapping their positions and changing sizes

Comment: Can the web views reload the content, or has it been dynamically created somehow? You should just be able to get the URLs of each view and tell the other view to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following might work.

Sample GitHub project at: https://github.com/NSGod/SwapWebViews

I used two `NSBox`s placed in the window, and the 2 `WebView`s are separate like shown in the image below:

[image]

The Swap Webviews button's method simply calls `NSBox`'s [`setContentView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBox/setContentView:) with the desired `WebView`s.

[image]

Comment: brilliant, I didn't think about putting the WebViews in an NSBox and swapping the views. Now i just need them to resize appropriately :/ thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just swap positions and sizes of the 2 webviews:

```
NSRect tempRect = WebviewOne.frame;
WebviewOne.frame = WebViewTwo.frame;
WebviewTwo.frame = tempRect;
```

Comment: @hotpaw2 the views don't have different superviews, but it doesn't work, it just makes the larger webview smaller, but they both stay in the same position.